# Access Select query where source field is based on another column

Tags: ms-access, select

I am using MS Access for FX rate data. I have a table which lists currencies and their associated FX rate. Each column has the rate for a different month. e.g. "January 2019", "February 2019" etc

I have another table which has a list of dates and currencies, and I want to create a select query which returns the FX rate for the relevant currency for the relevant month.

I have created a field which converts the date to the format which matches the field name in the source data table, so for example the date 12/01/2019 is shown as January 2019 (and defined this as FX_period)

Basically, I want the source field used to be based on another field in that query.
For example:
January dates: source field is TBL10_FX_BS_Rates.[January 2019] AS FX_Rate
February dates: source field is TBL10_FX_BS_Rates.[February 2019] AS FX_Rate

So in the end I just have 3 columns: Date, Currency and FX rate

I have tried lots of things, including:
SET "[tablename]!["&FX_period&]" as FX_RATE

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

A table with a field for each mon/yr is not a normalized structure. Normalize TBL10_FX_BS_Rates structure then join tables in query. Actually, normalized table might be enough - depends if there are other fields in currencies table. Otherwise, use DLookup() - something like:

```
SELECT CurrencyDate, Currency, 
   DLookUp(Format([CurrencyDate],"mmmmyyyy"),"TBL10_FX_BS_Rates","Currency='" & [Currency] & "'") AS Rate
FROM Currencies;
```

Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention.